# getClass or Enum for type-dependent behavior

Tags: java, enums, introspection

Say I have a method that handles incoming data objects. It must handle each data type differently. Given the choice of two method signatures:

`void sendObjects(ObjectType enum, Collection<SendableObject> objects)` where `enum` denotes the type of objects in the collection and each object has a `ObjectType getType()` method,

and

`void sendObjects(Collection<SendableObject> objects)` where `getClass()` is used to determine the type.

Which approach is better and why? We recently had a discussion about this at my company, and I'm curious to hear what the community thinks.

Comment: Why does the type matter? You're not using inheritance correctly if you have to check the type of a `SendableObject`

Comment: As an example, consider messaging. You'd want a single method to handle any message. However, the actions that are taken depend on the type of message. The actions for a `DeleteDataMessage` would be very different from an `ErrorMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum doesn't add anything. In fact it risks being wrong, since the caller can mix it up. I'd go with checking the class or the `ObjectType getType()` on every object, but not send in the enum as argument.

Comment: +1 "A man with one clock knows what time it is. A man with two clocks is never sure." Avoid passing around redundant information without good reason.

Comment: Agreed. Enums seem very redundant. The object already knows its type, so why does it need an enum? I was just interested to see if the community had a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.